# Extend text using apply with two variables in R

Tags: r, dplyr, apply, sapply

I need to make a small piece of text using two variables, in R. I have the following data:

```
library(dplyr)
VAR <- c("Age", "Condition", "Condition2")
FIELDS <- c("", "Option1;Option2", "Set1;Set2")

df <- cbind(VAR, FIELDS) %>%
  as_data_frame()
```

And a function to write the text in a loop:

```
extending <- function(x, VAR){
  VARZ <- VAR[!is.na(x)]
  sapply(x, function(x){
    if(!is.na(x)){
      VARZ <- "XXXXX"
      opciones <-  strsplit(x, ";") 
      opciones <- opciones[[1]]
      opciones2 <- paste(
        "From ", VARZ, " here's ", opciones,
        sep=""
      )
    } else {
      opciones2 <- ""
    }
    opciones2
  })
}
```

When I use the function with the two variables:

```
extending(df$FIELDS, df$VAR)
```

The result is this:

```
# result 1
[[1]]
[1] "From XXXXX here's "

$`Option1;Option2`
[1] "From XXXXX here's Option1" "From XXXXX here's Option2"

$`Set1;Set2`
[1] "From XXXXX here's Set1" "From XXXXX here's Set2"
```

What I wanted to get is the following:

```
# result 2
[[1]]
[1] "From Age here's "

$`Option1;Option2`
[1] "From Condition here's Option1" "From Condition here's Option2"

$`Set1;Set2`
[1] "From Condition2 here's Set1" "From Condition2 here's Set2"
```

But if I disable the line `VARZ <- "XXXXX"` I get something completely different:

```
# result 3
                               Option1;Option2                  Set1;Set2                    
[1,] "From Age here's "        "From Age here's Option1"        "From Age here's Set1"       
[2,] "From Condition here's "  "From Condition here's Option2"  "From Condition here's Set2" 
[3,] "From Condition2 here's " "From Condition2 here's Option1" "From Condition2 here's Set1"
```

I have tried some variations but ended with even more weird results and not understanding very much what I'm doing.

Would it be a way to write a loop that reuses each variable in a "proper" way to write the text as in the `# result 2` chunk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a quick base r code:

```
 VAR <- c("Age", "Condition", "Condition2")
 FIELDS=c(" ", "Option1;Option2", "Set1;Set2")
 Map(function(x,y)paste("from",x,"here's",y),VAR,strsplit(FIELDS,";"))

 $Age
 [1] "from Age here's  "

 $Condition
 [1] "from Condition here's Option1" "from Condition here's Option2"

 $Condition2
 [1] "from Condition2 here's Set1" "from Condition2 here's Set2"
```

of course you can shorten your code, only if you are not interested in the names: which you can set later on

```
 Map(paste,"from",VAR,"here's",strsplit(FIELDS,";"))
```

Comment: Thanks! works perfectly! I also added `collapse = "\n"` to print them in different lines.